# How about 30~ish BizTalk applications, good practice?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

Trying to introduce BTDF for deployment, having a legacy of 30ish solutions, with the principle of 1:1 mapping between solution and biztalk application, this will result in 30ish BizTalk applications deployed. Never did this or saw this before, would this consider a bad practice or does it impact performance in any sense?

If this is not a good way to go for deployment, could you please suggest a better way to deploy without major refactor the solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a 1:1 relationship between Visual Studio Solution and BizTalk Application with BTDF is the best way to manage your apps.

The key is to have absolutely **no cross solution references**.  Even if that means deploying the same Schema in different Applications.  There's nothing wrong with that.  What you want to do is eliminate any dependencies.

The only minor consequence is having to create custom Pipelines and configuring Xml Disassmebler and Xml Assembler components.  See here: [BizTalk: Improve Deployment and Tracking by Always Creating Custom Pipelines](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35656.biztalk-improve-deployment-and-tracking-by-always-creating-custom-pipelines.aspx)

Comment: so application count doesn't really matter? I am a bit hesitant since I never see these many and worry about any performance hit.. btw, how do you deploy the same schema in different solutions? I thought you have to deploy it in a common one and reference it (which causes the nightmare when any update to the common artifact required)

Comment: So long as you have BizTalk Server Enterprise Edition, 30 Applications is not in any way a problem.  There's no 'performance' considerations.